# Not showing the "print('yes')" statement

Tags: python, random

```
def subtract1(a, b):
    return a - b
    if random.randint(0,100) < 99:
        print("Yes")
print(subtract(20, 10)
```

I have tried many different ways of using a random number gen but can't seem to find one that works. I am now quite sure that it has to do something with the other code but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `return` ends the function.

Comment: And the code won't even compile given the mismatched parentheses on the final line. Suggest you edit to make it match what you *actually* have (cut'n'paste is your friend).

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function in the print statement you have [print(subtract(number1, number2)]. Your function is named subtract1 so try to call subtract1 instead of subtract as the function name. Plus the return statement is stopping it before it reaches the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

editing the function as the following way will solve your problem
Note that for any function the return statement always ends the function
and any other lines written in the function body after the return statement will never be compiled. also you call the function with the same name of its defination

```py
import random

def subtract(a, b):
    if random.randint(0,100) < 99:
        print("Yes")
    return a - b


print(subtract(20, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `return` immediately at the beginning of the function it returns the value you passed (`a-b`) and won't pass to the rest of the code.

if you want to print a-b before running the code below you can look at `yield`:

```
import random

def subtract(a,b):
    yield a-b
    if random.randint(1,100) < 99: print("yes")
   
print(subtract(20,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what's your intention but if what I'm thinking is right,
your code should be like this

```
def subtract1(a, b):
    if random.randint(0,100) < 99:
        print("Yes")
    return a - b

print(subtract(20, 10))
```

return statement returns the return value and at the same time ends the function.

So if it were for you to print the subtracted value first and print Yes later,
it has to be like this

```
def subtract1(a, b):
    return a - b

print(subtract(20, 10))
if random.randint(0,100) < 99:
    print("Yes")
```